# TextInputLayout isn't showing

Tags: android, xml, material-design

I'm quite new in the world of Android app development. I'm currently trying out some basic things. Currently I'm trying to achieve a floating label like the ones seen in various material design apps.

What I'm trying to do is get a `CardView` and place a `TextInputLayout` in that card.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/labeltest"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:hint="floating label"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Now when I do this, I get a CardView like I'm supposed to get, but the TextInputLayout doesn't show up. However, I can tap it, after which it focusses and lets me enter text. (see example below)

I would like to add that I'm testing it on a virtual machine, not on an actual device.

Thanks.

[image: Example 1]

Edit: As per request, `colors.xml`

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#E43F3F</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#E12929</color>
    <color name="primary_darker">#CC1D1D</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</color>

    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="jet">#222222</color>
    <color name="oil">#333333</color>
    <color name="monsoon">#777777</color>
    <color name="jumbo">#888888</color>
    <color name="aluminum">#999999</color>
    <color name="base">#AAAAAA</color>
    <color name="iron">#CCCCCC</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="Trans_text">#a8ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in edit text. In your current code, parent has wrap_content and child has match_parent which cancel each other to 0, so make sure to have proper child and parent layout_params

Comment: And it is recommended to use `TextInputEditText` with `TextInputLayout` instead of plain `EditText` https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputEditText.html

Comment: @MohammedAtif Just tried `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText`. When I use that, it becomes completely invisible and unclickable

Comment: Can you add please the `colors.xml` file?

Comment: @IulianPopescu added

Comment: did you change the layout_height to wrap_content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll read the [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.google.com/style/color.html#) you'll find that the `colorAccent` is used as color for the line below your field. You have the `colorAccent` set to white (see `colors.xml` file) so, my guess is that the `TextInputLayout` is blending with the background color of the `parent` which is also white or something similar. Try changing the `colorAccent` in red or something to see if it was the problem.